# Typescript debugging React-Native

Tags: typescript, debugging, react-native, promise, source-maps

Debugging a yellowbox warning from React-Native of: `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection`.
This just cropped up and I'm not sure where as fairly large code base.

The problem is the warning only refers to localhost blobs.

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Network Error
Error: Network Error
    at createError (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:64300:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:64208:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:15785:39)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:15548:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:15379:16)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:15489:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:16325:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:2384:44)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:2154:17
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/b6bcf60a-2862-40b3-bc2f-8bded9973f69:2346:11)
```

I have enabled `sourceMaps` in tsconfig, sourceMaps are enabled in `.babelrc`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @PratikBhattacharya I didn't find a great way to debug it. I stopped the yellow errors blocking my screen with `console.disableYellowBox = true` in my index.tsx

Comment: are you getting this error while trying to make an API call? It looks like that your app is trying to make a call to some API, and the call is failing. This error generally props up from the xhr module (xhr is internally called by axios or fetch)